# Venv using canopy and python 2.7

Tags: python, enthought

I have installed canopy express and changed the path variable so now I have it as my default python (I am using version 2.7 of python).

Now I am having an issue trying to create a virtual environment as canopy does not work with virtualenv and I must use venv.

When I try to create my enviroment with

```
>>> venv -u path\directory
```

I get this error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
venv -u canopy
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `venv` command should be issued from a "Canopy Command Prompt" window (e.g. from a `C:>` prompt), not at a Python prompt as you are doing. You can open a Canopy Command Prompt from the Windows Start Menu or from the Tools menu in the Canopy application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonathan. I tried and got an "no such file or directory pyvenv.cfg" error... any idea what I could be doing wrong?